# How to align labels in a c# web form

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am trying to create an online bookstore. When a user clicks on a button (representing a genre), the book picture, name, author etc. are displayed.
The images are positioned next to each other, with the name's label below it, the author's label below the name's label and so forth.

The labels are thus next to each other.

I Have tried using CSS to set the width of labels

```
label {

    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}
```

The labels width is influenced by the length of the book's name resulting in them not to be aligned

Comment: Please show us your html source part

Comment: <asp:Label CssClass="label" ID="lblName1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Bookstore.aspx.cs" Inherits="Bookstore.Bookstore" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel  ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet1.css" />

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML and CSS:

```css
figure {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: smaller;
  text-indent: 0;
  border: thin silver solid;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

img.scaled {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <p><img class=scaled src="https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/st-tropez.jpg"
    alt="St. Tropez">
  <figcaption>Saint Tropez and its
    fort in the evening sun</figcaption>
</figure>
```

You could put your label inside `<figcaption>` tag

```
<figure>
  <p><img class=scaled src="https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/st-tropez.jpg"
    alt="St. Tropez">
  <figcaption><asp:Label CssClass="label" ID="lblName1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: I used figure and a <p> tag for each image/label and the text is aligned perfectly now

Comment: I will be sure to do so, I am trying to earn reputation.